java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore
   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.hari.solutionhub, PID: 9013

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore;Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider$Factory;)V in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider' appears in /data/app/~~2naD0UeoMZQtJiv_kdxOHw==/com.hari.solutionhub-MfFrJ8czF6I-otlSAQjoVQ==/base.apk)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel.getInstance(FragmentManagerViewModel.java:52)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2703)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:117)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.lambda$init$3$androidx-fragment-app-FragmentActivity(FragmentActivity.java:139)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onContextAvailable(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.kt:84)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.kt:331)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:216)
    at com.hari.solutionhub.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

I am trying to solve this error from stackexchange and YouTube but did not found solution.
How to solve it? Please help me to solve this error!

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.
